# Nexus not downloading artifacts through Hudson

Tags: maven, hudson, nexus

I'm trying to integrate Hudson with Nexus. 
As I build a project without using Nexus, its build is successful.

When I try building it with Nexus, I get the following build errors:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 12:22:22-0300)
Maven home: /var/lib/hudson/maven/slavebundle/bundled-maven
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/hudson/maven/slavebundle/lib/maven3-eventspy-runtime.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/hudson/maven/slavebundle/bundled-maven/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.



[DEBUG] Connected to remote
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.SettingsBuildingRequestHandler - Using settings document ID: ff56412a-102c-4256-80bf-f234990c91ba

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]  

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.378s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 12 11:37:31 BRST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/30M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - Build failed with exception(s)
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - [1] org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 in nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
[DEBUG] Closing connection to remote
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 in nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[DEBUG] Waiting for process to finish
[DEBUG] Result: 1
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: Tracker #26 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

And this is my configured Settings on Hudson:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

I don't know why is it not downloading from central repository into the nexus public repository.

Can someone shed some light into this?

Comment: Is you nexus open to the internet to download the needed artifacts which are not yet in your nexus?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, it is man. Checked with iptables off and still couldn't download. I tried with Hudson without Nexus, which runs on the same machine, and It worked like a charm. It also works if Nexus is on another machine. So I'll try to reinstall it all one more time.

Comment: Have you checked inside Nexus the proxy configuration if this is working?

Comment: Sorry, it is automatically blocking it, the error is  java.security.providerexception java.security.keyexception

Comment: I tried allowing the proxy, but it still gets this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. It was throwing as SSL Exception when trying to access the Central Repository.

This exception was automatically blocking my access.

I went to Central Repository > Configuration and changed the Remote Storage Location url to: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ and right-clicked on Central and clicked Allow Proxy.

It worked like a charm after that.

I hope this helps someone, because I lost almost two days to this.

EDIT (19/11/2015):

If you're running your openjdk using RedHat/CentOS, there's a bug preventing access via SSL, just as pointed by @rseddon in the comments section. The workarounds are here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-7999?focusedCommentId=306680&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-306680

If you're in a hurry, this is the one I used:

Add the following line to ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/java.security :

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC,ECDHE,ECDH

Now I can use the https link on my Central Repo.

Comment: Were you running openjdk on a redhat/centos OS?  If so, there is a bug that prevents it from accessing central via ssl.  See here for a workaround: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-7999?focusedCommentId=306680&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-306680

Comment: I was running it on CentOs. Thanks man, I'll have a look at it.